# Building a Docker images fails when a User tries to execute javac

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile, but if I add a User it keeps failing during the building process. If I remove the User the building process of the images succeeds, but I need the User, cause it is a requirement for the Code Climate engine I am working on.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java

MAINTAINER DavidRenz

RUN groupadd app -g 9000 && useradd -g 9000 -u 9000 -r -s /bin/false app 

VOLUME /code
WORKDIR /code

COPY . /usr/src/app

USER app

RUN javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java
CMD ["java", "/usr/src/app/bin/Pmd"]
```

Log:

```
Step 7 : USER app
 ---> Running in 896795a6bb63
 ---> 09c5179159a8
Removing intermediate container 896795a6bb63
Step 8 : RUN javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java
 ---> Running in 3e1a335f8edf
javac: file not found: /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
The command '/bin/sh -c javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: The command `/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/javac HelloWorld.java` does not process "`HelloWorld.java`" as an argument of `javac`. If you add `"` around the `javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java` at the line _`RUN javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java`_ it should work. Could you try?

Comment: If I use `RUN "javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java"` the building process fails with `Step 8 : RUN "javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java"
 ---> Running in 1ce92fa8d406
/bin/sh: 1: javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c "javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java"' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: Add the full path please: `RUN "/usr/bin/javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java"`

Comment: Same problem `Step 8 : RUN "/usr/bin/javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java"
 ---> Running in 8e6bbb63a4c6
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java"' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: Is your path ok? your path contain .../bin/Pmd.java and usually bin is for binary (compiled) files. java files are not usually stored in folder with this name. Maybe the path is wrong.

Comment: I guess everything is okay with the path, as everything works fine if I kill the `User app` line.

Comment: Could you just remove the RUN line and try with an built image to "javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java". It may be a permission issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a permissions error: up until your `USER app` command, your container is running as `root`, so `/usr/src/app` is owned by `root`, and not readable by the `app` user.

I believe if you replace the `USER app, RUN javac...` sequence with the following steps, it will work:

```
RUN javac /usr/src/app/bin/Pmd.java
RUN chmod -R app:app /usr/src/app

USER app
```